# Search result showing my product's in Indian Currency

Tags: seo, google, google-search

We have an ecommerce website builder where users create their online store. One of my clients is facing an issue with Google search results. When searching for a product on Google, the result is shown in Indian currency. Nowhere on the website is the price mentioned in Indian currency. The website's customers are also from Pakistan, but the price is in Indian currency. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?